# Is $\left( \Omega, \mathcal{F}_{1}, \mu |_{\mathcal{F}_{1}} \right)$ also $\sigma$-finite?

Tags: measure-theory

If $\left( \Omega, \mathcal{F},  \mu \right)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space then for $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}_{1} \subset \mathcal{F}$, is $\left( \Omega, \mathcal{F}_{1},  \mu |_{\mathcal{F}_{1}} \right)$ also $\sigma$-finite?
I was solving a problem where I needed to apply Radon-Nikodym theorem, for that I need $\mathcal{F}_{1}$ to be $\sigma$-finite with respect to the restricted measure $\mu |_{\mathcal{F}_{1}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $(\Bbb{R},B(\Bbb{R}),\lambda)$ ($\lambda$ being Lebesgue measure) and $(\Bbb{R},\{\Bbb{R},\emptyset\},\lambda|_{\{\Bbb{R},\emptyset\}})$.

Or more generally, consider any $\sigma$ finite but not finite measure space and just take your $\mathcal{F}_1=\{\Omega,\emptyset\}$.

Comment: I'm not sure if "of course" is really appropriate :-) Nice example anyway ! (+1)

Comment: @Surb Sorry, I just meant "there's a lot of examples". Thanks!